# Redirect existing Windows socket to different interface

Tags: tcp

I have a laptop with two network cards, one wired and one wireless. Both interfaces are on the same subnet.
I have been able to use the Wi-Fi interface for the web navigation and the wired interface for the internal lan traffic changing the local route table and including a default gateway for the Wi-Fi interface only.
This was the easy part.
My aim is to able to maintain exactly the same existing internal lan tcp connections redirecting them from the lan interface to the wireless interface when I undock the notebook.
To my understanding a Windows socket is described by a unique 4-tuple consisting of source and destination IP addresses and port numbers, i.e. of local and remote socket addresses.
What I tried to do was to intercept the undocking event and trigger a script that deleted the wired interface addresses and set the Wi-Fi interface addresses exactly to the same addresses the wired interface had. Unfortunately the internal lan sockets are recreated using the Wi-Fi interface, that is the source ports are different from the ones used by the wired interface, even if the source address and the remote address and ports are the same previously used by the wired interface.
Is it possible to redirect existing tcp connections to different interface?
Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Since this may not be so readable, I will make a specific example:

Let’s say my wired interface has assigned the address 192.168.1.2 and the wireless interface has assigned the address 192.168.1.3 and both interfaces are simultaneously active.

I establish a tcp connection using the address 192.168.1.2 and the port number 50885 as the source address and the source port and the address 192.168.1.5 and the port number 445 as the remote address and remote port.

After establishing the above tcp connection I undock the notebook (that is equivalent to disconnecting the Ethernet cable).

I want to know if it is possible to maintain exactly the above tcp connection by first disabling the Ethernet interface (or releasing the Ethernet ip address and deleting it to prevent Windows from killing tcp connections by disabling the wired interface) and then assigning the address 192.168.1.2 to the wireless interface.

My test tells me that this is not possible but I really would like to make this possible.

Comment: Unreadable. Can you reformat to make the question more readable?

Comment: You mean about spacing or about the content?

Comment: I meant the spacing. The example helps a lot though!